# How do you get the tables odd tr and change the style?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a table which has the ID="movie", the standard CSS background-color is #5f6268 for even rows and #b5bdbf for odd rows. However, I have a search function to get rid of rows I don't want to see when searching. The colors gets all mixed up and it all looks bad.

How can I possibly insert into my javascript code that picks up the tr of the table with the ID "movie" and adds the background color #5f6268 for even rows and #b5bdbf for odd rows?(The code also has to overlook the tr's that has the style display none)

I have tried doing

```
document.getElementById("movie").tr:odd.backgroundColor="red";
```

as a test, did not work.

Comment: Please add HTML and CSS and possibly js for your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it with pure css:

```css
#movie tr:nth-child(even) td { background: #5f6268; }
#movie tr:nth-child(odd) td { background: #b5bdbf; }
```

edit for given requirements...

depending on how you are hiding/showing rows you should be able to look at whatever property during a scan of rows to re-color, e.g.

```js
functionToRunAfterSearchCompletes() {
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#movie tr');
    var odd = false;
    for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
       if(rows[i].style.display !== 'none') { // or whatever your display mechanism is
           odd = !odd; // toggle back and forth between odd/even
           rows[i].style.backgroundColor = odd ? '#b5bdbf' : '#5f6268'; // set color
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that every time someone use the search bar some rows gets removed and every second row wont be every second row anymore.
#movies tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #5f6268;
}
#movies tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #b5bdbf;
}
#movies tr:first-child {
  background-color: #5ba1af;
}

Comment: @user10885911 If you have requirements like that, they should be in the question. That said, I’m guessing they’re not removed but rather hidden, which is why the css doesn’t work.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Sorry for not clarifying that. I have added it to the question now. My bad.